# Using Xargs to read the input from a console

Tags: grep, xargs

This is the script I have written

```
zgrep -i xxxx FileA | grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" | uniq | cut -d "=" -f2 | xargs
```

Before the point of `xargs` being used my o/p is

```
01982893213982312 - RID 1
32103213213213213 - RID 2
32103213213213343 - RID 3
32103213213251261 - RID 4
```

For every RID present here, there is a corresponding line in File B. I am planning to do like the below after the:

```
zgrep -i xxxx FileA | grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" | uniq | cut -d "=" -f2 | xargs|
{grep RID1 in file B, grep RID2 in file B,grep RID3 in file B, grep RID4 in file B}
```

Now my only question is how will I refer RID1,2,3,4 with xargs....

Comment: Can you give a few lines from File A and File B and specify specifically what input you want to give at the shell? What do your scripts look like so far?

Comment: How big is FileA?  How many lines, that is?  If it is only a few (say, under a thousand), then one set of options is available; if it is large, the options are fewer.  Also, is the RID simply one field of many on each line of FileA, or is it the only data on each line?

Comment: Actually the size of file A is large more than thousand. Regarding RID Output of file 1,  it is say 09877326369900 92828282828 020292929202 . These are the three outputs from file A. Now I need to fetch the corresponding lines of file B that has the output of file A... for this I need to read the output of file A from the console itself and not store it in a temp file

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do that is to pipe the data such as:

```
script1 fileA | script2 fileB
```

This approach allows you to pass more arguments, and stream through fileB..

Comment: How will the second script receives the input one by one from the first

Comment: This is the script I have written
zgrep -i xxxx FileA|grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*"|uniq|cut -d "=" -f2|xargs

Before the point of Xargs being used my o/p is 
01982893213982312 - RID 1
32103213213213213 - RID 2
32103213213213343 - RID 3
32103213213251261 - RID 4


For every RID present here, there is a corresponding line in File B. I am planning to do like the below after the 

zgrep -i xxxx FileA|grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*"|uniq|cut -d "=" -f2|xargs|{grep RID1 in file B, grep RID2 in file B,grep RID3 in file B, grep RID4 in file B}

Now my only question is how will I refer RID1,2,3,4 with xargs....

Comment: I ve edited the question .. Plz look at that for better formatting

Comment: Guys I have figured out the answer ... we can use the below        xargs -0 -I string zcat XXXXX| agrep -dEOE string..  Thus xargs will pass the values one by one

Answer (score 0):

If the data in FileA is one RID per line, then the obvious choice is (classically) [`fgrep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/fgrep.html) or (using the more modern notation) [`grep -F`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).  POSIX un-standardized `fgrep` (replacing it with `grep -F`) in the 2004 version.  However, `fgrep` has a very long pedigree; it was part of 7th Edition UNIX™ circa 1978, for example.

```
fgrep -f FileA FileB
grep -F -f FileA FileB
```

If the data in FileA is not in the 'one RID per line' format, make it so!

---

> But does fgrep read i/p from console

It does if you tell it to, but you don't want it to read from the console; you want it to read from standard input.  'Console input' means 'you typing', roughly.  (That said, I checked the behaviour of `grep -F` by using `grep -F -f - /etc/passwd` and then typing `/bin/` on the 'console' (terminal) and then indicated EOF.  It worked fine.)

If you are using `bash`, you can use 'process substitution' to get the result you want:

```
grep -F -f <(zgrep -i xxxx FileA | grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" | uniq | cut -d "=" -f2) FileB
```

Process substitution runs the command inside `<( ... )` so that its output goes to a 'file' (actually, a file descriptor in `/dev/fd`, usually), and the name is given to the command (`grep`) as a regular file name argument.

If you're not using `bash`, you can probably use this instead (and this will work OK with `bash` too, and may even be preferable):

```
zgrep -i xxxx FileA | grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" | uniq | cut -d "=" -f2 |
grep -F -f - FileB
```

The lone dash means 'read from standard input' in this context; it is a common convention for commands.  It works fine on Mac OS X 10.7.4; there's a strong probability it will work elsewhere too.

Comment: Its in one RID per line ... But does fgrep read i/p from console

Comment: This is the script I have written
zgrep -i xxxx FileA|grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*"|uniq|cut -d "=" -f2|xargs

Before the point of Xargs being used my o/p is 
01982893213982312 - RID 1
32103213213213213 - RID 2
32103213213213343 - RID 3
32103213213251261 - RID 4


For every RID present here, there is a corresponding line in File B. I am planning to do like the below after the 

zgrep -i xxxx FileA|grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*"|uniq|cut -d "=" -f2|xargs|{grep RID1 in file B, grep RID2 in file B,grep RID3 in file B, grep RID4 in file B}

Now my only question is how will I refer RID1,2,3,4 with xargs....

Comment: I ve edited the question .. Plz look at that for better formatting